# edit the program and run it, find mistake if they exist in the program

Tags: python-3.x

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3IhV.png)

among the correction to be made, "pi" is not imported and i changed 1_VAL to 1_val so that the two variables match. but my program is still not working.

here is the correction i made

```
from math import sin, cos, pi
x = pi/4
1_val = math.sin^2(x) + math.cos^2(x)
print 1_val
```

it's telling me this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwdwB.png)

Comment: Please read [An image of your code is not helpful](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) and then edit your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Your variable name cannot start with a number. It must start with a non-digit or an underscore `_`

Also,if You only functions `cos` and `sin` from `math` You have to use those functions directly (without referencing the `math` module). Moreover, by doing this You will not have the `pi` value You are expecting.

Your square calculations are also not performed correctly.

try this:

```
import math

x = math.pi / 4

val_1 = math.pow(math.sin(x), 2) + math.pow(math.cos(x), 2)

print val_1
```

I advise You to read some tutorials on Python. Here is a good example to get You started: http://www.pythonlearn.com/

Comment: okay, thanks. when i edited it as you said i am getting this                                                 -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------       Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/youss/PycharmProjects/exerciceschapA/eee.py", line 3, in <module>
    _val = math.sin^2(x) + math.cos^2(x)
NameError: name 'math' is not defined

Process finished with exit code 1